# Curious behavior of split function in Python

Tags: python, performance

I'm processing a large amount of `:` splitted data with Python. And I'm having a strange situation.

This is the original code written by my colleague:

```
tag = word[i].split(":")[0].decode('utf8')
value = int(word[i].split(":")[1])
```

And I think it is inefficient since it called the `split` function twice where one single call should suffice, so I change it to this:

```
tokens = word[i].split(":")
tag = tokens[0].decode('utf8')
value = int(tokens[1])
```

And very strange thing happens after this:

I used a log to record the performance of the code, and it takes about `10 second`s to process 1000 lines of data, but after my modification it takes about `50 seconds` to process 1000 lines of data.

Why this happens? Isn't ONE call supposed to be faster than TWO calls?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You might want to show the code surrounding that piece you've already shown. 10 seconds sounds WAY too slow for processing 1000 of anything, let alone 50 seconds. I'm betting the performance impact is elsewhere, not here.

Comment: hmmm curious... are there more than 2 entries when you `split`... otherwise it could be the extra allocation of those entries to tokens... just a guess....

Comment: @JoshSmeaton It involves querying Redis several times in each line, and each line consists of tens of : separated words.

Comment: Test it in isolation or don't test it at all. It's far more likely that something changed somewhere else in the flow, such as the time to go to Redis and back or some such.

Comment: @Amber Thanks. I think I need to check Redis.

Comment: If there is always exactly 1 ':', it will be more efficient to use `word[i].partition(":")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logs are not a good way to benchmark a short code section - there are quite a few other things happening in your system. Using the timeit module will give more accurate results:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import timeit
>>> word = ["answer:42"]
>>> def split1(word=word):
...     tag = word[0].split(":")[0].decode("utf-8")
...     value = int(word[0].split(":")[1])
... 
>>> def split2(word=word):
...     tokens = word[0].split(":") 
...     tag = tokens[0].decode("utf-8")
...     value = int(tokens[1])
... 
>>> t2 = timeit.Timer("split2()", "from __main__ import split2")
>>> t2.timeit()
2.5862038135528564
>>> t1 = timeit.Timer("split1()", "from __main__ import split1")
>>> t1.timeit()
2.8647868633270264
```